# Show memory usage of processes with the same name

Tags: linux

What's the easiest way to show memory usage of processes with the same name?

Not individually, but the total usage.

To figure out how much things like Chrome consume memory.

Answer (score 0):

I would select all the process with `pgrep`, print resident memory with `ps` and sum it using `awk`:

```bsh
ps -p $(pgrep -d, -x chrome) -ho rss | awk '{s+=$1} END {printf "%i", s}'
```

For some process it's probably better to look for full command line instead of name. On my distribution, using chromium:

```bsh
ps -p $(pgrep -d, --full /usr/lib/chromium/chromium) -ho rss | awk '{s+=$1} END {printf "%i", s}'
```

Comment: running this command gives me `error: only one heading option may be specified`(from ps). I'm on Gentoo

Comment: Hum, maybe try `--no-headers -o rss` instead?

Comment: `ps -p $(pgrep -d, -x chrome) --no-headers -o rss | awk '{s+=$1} END {printf "%i", s}' `
 same.

Comment: Damned, I guess we have different ps implementations or version. What about: `ps -p $(pgrep -d, -x chrome) -o rss | awk '$1 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ {s+=$1} END {printf "%i", s}'` ?

Comment: nah. I guess the problem is that the `pgrep` command gives output in the following form `3402 chrome,3410 chrome`

Comment: You can get rid of `pgrep` using `ps ho rss -C chrome`

Comment: it works, but doesn't seem right. Because it says it uses only 8MB, when it's at least 1GB. 
`{printf "%i", (s/1000/1000)}`  gives `8`